# argos gnome extension not updating top bar automatically

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweaks

Argos is a handy tool that put output into the Gnome Top Bar. My problem is I have to re-save the file in ~/.config/argos to get it to update anything in the Top Bar. Am I missing something?

my argos .sh file which I have placed in the above folder is

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 echo "$(date %S)"
```

which should show the seconds in the top bar every second.
the problem exists for anything else, like a random number generation.

https://github.com/p-e-w/argos
"Make it executable and drop it into ~/.config/argos, and you should see something like this"
"As the plugin updates every second, new log entries are shown almost without delay."

Ubuntu 20.04, 5.8.0-50-generic

Comment: one workaround which is silly is to write a script to save the argos.sh file every second.

Comment: Read the documentation. The name of your script defines how frequently it is updated.

Comment: got it, thanks. filename is now xxx.1s.sh for 1 second interval.

Comment: Would be good to write out your solution as an answer to help future users. Comments may disappear anytime. It is perfectly fine here to answer your own question.